# how to show a console message when element is in focus?

Tags: javascript

can you please help me how to show a console message `any child element of a parent is focused` ?I am focusing through `tab`. When My focus move to any child element of a parent . i want to show a console message . here is my code

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#rc20p3');
container.addEventListener('focusin', (e) => {
  console.log(e.relatedTarget);
  if (container.contains(e.relatedTarget)) console.log('focus is now outside of container');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text"/>
  <input type="text"/>
  <div id="rc20p3" class="rc20panel"><div class="rh02panel rh02carousel rh02carouselinit rh02random rh02p3   rh02stopped " data-trackas="rc20:panel3" role="button"><div class="rh02w2 rh02-slide1  bgimg rh02noscrim rh02current " data-position="0"><div class="rh02w3">
    <div class="rh02-pcontent">
        <div class="rh02-logo-md">

        <h2 class="rh02-ttl">Expanding the Possibilities of Hybrid Cloud with Oracle EVP Clay Magouyrk</h2>
        <div class="rh02-cta">
            <div class="obttns">
                <div><a data-lbl="cta-0209-panelx-pn-olive-hybrid-ondemand" href="https://www.oracle.com/events/live/expanding-possibilities-hybrid-cloud/?source=:ow:o:h:feb:::RC_WWMK201212P00001:Cta_0209_OLiveOCIfeb9OnDemandPanel3&amp;intcmp=:ow:o:h:feb:::RC_WWMK201212P00001:Cta_0209_OLiveOCIfeb9OnDemandPanel3">Watch on demand</a></div>

                <div><a data-lbl="cta-0209-panelx-pn-olive-hyrbid-pr-news" href="https://www.oracle.com/news/announcement/oracle-expands-hybrid-cloud-portfolio-with-roving-edge-infrastructure-020921.html?intcmp=OHPpanelx">Oracle Hybrid Cloud news</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div><div class="rh02w2 rh02-slide2 darktheme bgimg rh02noscrim  " data-position="1" style=""><div class="rh02w3">
    <div class="rh02-pcontent">
        <h2 class="rh02-ttl">Oracle ATP recognized in Gartner Critical Capabilities Report</h2>

        <div class="rh02-leadin">
            <p>Oracle ranked highest in all four Use Cases in Gartner “2020 Critical Capabilities for Cloud Database Management Systems for Operational Use Cases” report.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="rh02-cta">
            <div class="obttns">
                <div><a data-lbl="cta-0201-panelx-pn-gart-newcopyandimage-db-crit-caps" href="https://www.oracle.com/database/gartner-dbms.html?intcmp=OHP0201">Read the Gartner report</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div><div class="rh02w2 rh02-slide3  bgimg   " data-position="2"><div class="rh02w3">
    <div class="rh02-pcontent">
        <h2 class="rh02-ttl oserif">From farmer to fork</h2>

        <div class="rh02-leadin">
            <p>Land O’Lakes relies on Oracle Cloud to power its supply chain.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="rh02-leadin">&nbsp;</div>

        <div class="rh02-cta">
            <div class="obttns">
                <div><a data-lbl="cta-0120-panelx-pn-cust-landolakes" href="https://www.oracle.com/customers/land-o-lakes/?intcmp=OHP0120">Learn more</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div><div class="rh02w2 rh02-slide4 darktheme bgimg rh02noscrim  " data-position="3"><div class="rh02w3">
    <div class="rh02-pcontent">
        <h2 class="rh02-ttl rh02-longttl">Try Cloud Free Tier</h2>

        <div class="rh02-leadin">
            <p>Oracle Cloud Free Tier lets anyone build, test, and deploy applications on Oracle Cloud—for free. Sign up once, get access to two free offers.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="rh02-cta">
            <div class="obttns">
                <div><a data-lbl="cta-1030-panelX-free-tier-pn" href="https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/?source=:ow:o:h:feb::OHPpn1030&amp;intcmp=:ow:o:h:feb::OHPpn1030">Start your trial today</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div><div class="rh02w2 rh02-slide5 darktheme bgimg rh02noscrim  " data-position="4"><div class="rh02w3">
    <div class="rh02-pcontent">
        <h2 class="rh02-ttl rh02-longttl">70,000 people vaccinated in first week</h2>

        <div class="rh02-leadin">
            <p>Oracle builds Health Management Cloud used for COVID-19 clinical trials in U.S.</p>

            <p>Ghana uses the same cloud system to distribute Yellow Fever vaccine</p>
        </div>

        <div class="rh02-cta">
            <div class="obttns">
                <div><a data-lbl="cta-1123-panelx-health-covid-pn" href="https://www.oracle.com/corporate/citizenship/health/?intcmp=OHP1123-pn" title="Learn more">Learn more</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div><ul class="rh02nav"><li><a class="rh02cnav" href="#1" title="View Slide 1"><b>View Slide 1</b></a></li><li><a class="o-hf " href="#2" title="View Slide 2"><b>View Slide 2</b></a></li><li><a class="o-hf " href="#3" title="View Slide 3"><b>View Slide 3</b></a></li><li><a class="o-hf " href="#4" title="View Slide 4"><b>View Slide 4</b></a></li><li><a class="o-hf " href="#5" title="View Slide 5"><b>View Slide 5</b></a></li></ul></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Steps to reproduce**.

- click on first input field or focus first input field using `Tab`.
- press Tab again it will go to next input field
- Now If we tab again it goes to `child element` of parent `rc20p3` it should print a console.log. currently it is not showing log

yes focus event is triggered `e.relatedTarget` gives input field it should give `anchor` as it goes to that element

Comment: Can't reproduce - I get a console log on Chrome 88.0.4324.150

Comment: Please don't post links to your code as links can die over time making your question meaningless. Always include the relevant code, right here in your question. Also, your HTML is not valid as the closing `body` and `html` tags don't match up with their opening counterparts.

Comment: @ScottMarcus are you able to reproduce

Comment: @esqew focus to input field .then tab it move to another input field. but again tab focus move to `anchor tag` (Now I want a console statement)

Comment: `e.relatedTarget`  should be `anchor` ? correct ?

Comment: @ScottMarcus pasting linked code as an edit to a question is not best practice, see: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/13762301), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344484/pasting-fiddle-snippet-into-original-question-as-an-edit/344512#344512), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348698/edits-that-add-ops-code-from-3rd-party-site-where-the-license-is-unavailable). Rather point out to the OP that they should include relevant code as a Snippet where possible.

Comment: yes focus event is triggered `e.relatedTarget` gives input field it should give `anchor` as it goes to that element

Comment: @pilchard Copying the OP's own code from a 3rd party site is recommended so that the question can be self-contained. The guidelines you linked to refer to licensed code and don't apply in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

console.log(e.relatedTarget.tagName) gives you "INPUT" when you tab to a link from an input box.

Whereas console.log(e.target.tagName); gives you "A" when you tab to a link from an input box.

e.target is probably what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand it right, but this might fix your problem.

```
const parent = document.querySelector('#rc20p3');
const children = Array.from(parent.children);

children.forEach(child => {
  child.addEventListener("focusin", () => console.log(" Your Text "))
}
```